# How can I access previous path in React using BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Can I find previous paths in the history object? E.g. I go to "/activity/55" from "/home". Can I get the string "/home" somehow when I'm in the component for "/activity/55"?

`history.goBack()` works and takes me back to "/home" so the information is in there?
[image]

Or am I trying to do this the wrong way. I've seen some passing the previous path to each component. Ideally I'd like avoid tracking it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you can't: `history.goBack` is a tiny wrapper around `window.history.go(-1)`. So the browser's native [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) object is what actually tracks it, vs the history wrapper used in react-router, and History doesn't expose the actual history stack state.